# Bind window to a scroll function, but custom scroll function as part of tumblr theme

Tags: jquery, scroll, jscrollpane, tumblr, mousewheel

I am trying to create a function which is triggered on scroll, the scroll function works horizontally, and is part of a pixel union custom theme (I believe). I've been able to get a scroll function working elsewhere but not from within the theme.

This is my js:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event){

scrollCh = function() {
    $content = $('.post');
    $caption = $('.overlay .caption p');
    $offSet = $content.offset();
    $left = event.pageX - $content.offset();

    $caption.addClass('scroll-para').css('display','block');
    if($content.offset().left < 50 ) {
        $('body').css('background','yellow');   
    }else{
        $('body').css('background','orange');
    }
    console.log($left, $content, $caption, $offSet);
}
});

$(window).bind('scroll click', function(){
  scrollCh();
  console.log('clicked');
});
```

I've added the bind on click to prove that my code is firing on at least one event.

My test tumblr is here: http://hoffman-test.tumblr.com/

The pixel union js is also calling various other scripts, at first I thought it might be jScrollPane, but now I think it might be a mousewheel script. http://www.adomas.org/javascript-mouse-wheel/ I have tried looking through the code but I am not sure how to implement something to detect if scrolling is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is watching the event:

```
 $(window).bind('mousewheel', function(){
   scrollCh();
   console.log('scrolling');
 });
```